# kivyMD HotReloadViewer error: NoneType' object has no attribute 'fbind'

Tags: kivymd

I am trying to run the kivyMD HotReloadViewer script and when I run this code I get an error message inside the HotReloadViewer widget that says: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fbind'. I have researched the error and it is explained that somewhere in the code a variable is not defined or a function is returning None. I am wondering if there is something I am missing here, or advice on debugging where undefined variable or function is located. I am running kivymd-0.104.2.dev0 and have watchdog installed.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
#:import KivyLexer kivy.extras.highlight.KivyLexer
#:import HotReloadViewer kivymd.utils.hot_reload_viewer.HotReloadViewer


BoxLayout:

    CodeInput:
        lexer: KivyLexer()
        style_name: "native"
        on_text: app.update_kv_file(self.text)
        size_hint_x: .7

    HotReloadViewer:
        size_hint_x: .3
        path: app.path_to_kv_file
        errors: True
        errors_text_color: 1, 1, 0, 1
        errors_background_color: app.theme_cls.bg_dark
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    path_to_kv_file = "kv_file.kv"

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def update_kv_file(self, text):
        with open(self.path_to_kv_file, "w") as kv_file:
            kv_file.write(text)


Example().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Example(MDApp):
    path_to_kv_file = "kv_file.kv"  # path to your KV file
```

Comment: It seems like that part of the script is working, because when I type code in the left pane of the app, the code I type is added to the “kv_file.kv” in the same directory. I am thinking maybe there is a typo in a class somewhere, like “fbind” should be “bind”.